# OpenCV Mat creation produces memory leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, opencv

My memory is getting full fairly quick once using the next piece of code. Valgrind shows a memory leak, but everything is allocated on stack and (supposed to be) freed once the function ends.

```
void mult_run_time(int rows, int cols)
{
    Mat matrix(rows,cols,CV_32SC1);
    Mat row_vec(cols,1,CV_32SC1);

    /* initialize vector and matrix */
    for (int col = 0; col < cols; ++col)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < rows; ++row)
        {
            matrix.at<unsigned long>(row,col) = rand() % ULONG_MAX;
        }

        row_vec.at<unsigned long>(1,col) = rand() % ULONG_MAX;
    }
    /* end initialization of vector and matrix*/

    matrix*row_vec;  
}

int main()
{
    for (int row = 0; row < 20; ++row)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < 20; ++col)
        {
            mult_run_time(row,col);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Valgrind shows that there is a memory leak in line `Mat row_vec(cols,1,CV_32CS1)`:

```
==9201== 24,320 bytes in 380 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 50 of 50
==9201==    at 0x4026864: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==9201==    by 0x40C0A8B: cv::fastMalloc(unsigned int) (in /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.3.1)
==9201==    by 0x41914E3: cv::Mat::create(int, int const*, int) (in /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.3.1)
==9201==    by 0x8048BE4: cv::Mat::create(int, int, int) (mat.hpp:368)
==9201==    by 0x8048B2A: cv::Mat::Mat(int, int, int) (mat.hpp:68)
==9201==    by 0x80488B0: mult_run_time(int, int) (mat_by_vec_mult.cpp:26)
==9201==    by 0x80489F5: main (mat_by_vec_mult.cpp:59)
```

Is it a known bug in OpenCV or am I missing something?

Comment: This may be unrelated, but are you sure that `CV_32SC1` are `unsigned long`? They look more like `int` to me... (I wonder whether you write in a memory space you're not really allowed to because unsigned long are bigger, in number of bits, than ints)

Comment: Fezvez is right, you are actually writing unallocated memory. And the results are unexpected.

Comment: Changed `unsigned long` to be `int` and `ULONG_MAX` to `INT_MAX`. Mem-leak remains.

Comment: What version of OpenCV are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 2.3.1 of OpenCV, which is currently the latest available (stable) version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no use in using unsigned long at

```
matrix.at<unsigned long>(row,col) = rand() % ULONG_MAX;
```

because rand() returns an intenger anyways, so there is no gain in the total range, so use unsigned int instead.

In the line:

```
row_vec.at<unsigned long>(1,col) = rand() % ULONG_MAX;
```

you are accessing an outside range index. In c++, vectors starts from 0 and not 1. And the matrix are stored row-by-row in opencv. You are acessing unallocated memory area, thats probably the reason why valgrind is finding memory leaks. Use:

```
row_vec.at<unsigned int>(col, 0) = rand() % ULONG_MAX;
```

I presume that you are not compiling your program in Debug Mode because if it were the case, opencv uses an assertion before accessing an index to make sure you are inside the total range of the vector, if you were compiling in debug mode, your program would throw an assertion failure during the execution of your code, what makes easier to track this kind of mistakes.  I recomend you to start prototyping your code in debug mode.

Comment: Oh cool thnx... And I guess you're right. The first time I have compiled OpenCV, was with `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE`. If I have changed the flag to DEBUG and recompile OpenCV again, will it build the debug libraries alongside the release ones and allow me to define to compile modes??

Comment: The only reason to recompile the code, instead of using the pre-built binaries ([link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/)) is to setup the use of third libraries, like EIGEN ([link](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/)). If that's not the case, you can go for the pre-built binaries right away. They already came with debug libraries files, just link against them and assertion failures will be thrown. They don't come with debug info, if you like to step trought OpenCV code during debug, you will need to recompile it with debug flag. (well, there is another reason...)

Answer (score 0):

I agree, partially with @IanMedeiros: here the proper casting **is** `unsigned int`.

However the real deal is that for **every** types of Mat's there is **only one** correct cast.
For the list check [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484475/what-are-the-upper-and-lower-limits-of-pixel-values-in-opencv).
The answer gives the correct casts for grayscale images right-away.

For **multi-channel images** you need to cast to `Vec<mat_type, num_channels>`.

The most common predefined Vec's from the opencv2 lib:

```
typedef Vec<uchar, 3> Vec3b; // this is how a color image gets usually loaded
typedef Vec<short, 3> Vec3s;
typedef Vec<ushort, 3> Vec3w;
typedef Vec<int, 3> Vec3i;
typedef Vec<float, 3> Vec3f;
typedef Vec<double, 3> Vec3d;
```