# What are the upper and lower limits and types of pixel values in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv

What are the upper and lower limits of pixel values in OpenCV and how can I get them?

The only limits I could figure out are `CV_8U` type Mat's, where the lower limit for pixel values in a channel is 0, the upper is 255. What are these values for other Mat's?

Say CV_32F, CV_32S?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

OpenCV Equivalent C/C++ data types:

`CV_8U` -> `unsigned char` (min = 0, max = 255)

`CV_8S` -> `char` (min = -128, max = 127)

`CV_16U` -> `unsigned short` (min = 0, max = 65535)

`CV_16S` -> `short` (min = -32768, max = 32767)

`CV_32S` -> `int` (min = -2147483648, max = 2147483647)

`CV_32F` -> `float`

`CV_64F` -> `double`

Check [this tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/) for data type ranges.

One thing to consider is that while displaying images of type `CV_32F` or `CV_64F` with `imshow` or `cvShowImage`, OpenCV expects values to be normalized between 0.0 and 1.0. Else, it saturates the pixel values.

Comment: Thank you! This should be on the front page of the OpenCV documentation

Comment: It would be nice if cv::Mat had a function to query this information

Comment: Are there any constants defined for these maximum values in the cv namespace?

Comment: Wait, but this is not guaranteed, is it? Because the C++ standard does not specify the bit-size of integral types. So either CV_32S is int32_t instead of int, or the bit size could (even though unlikely) vary. But there is not type like double64_t - so I guess that your mapping to types is right, whereas the limits **might** be false.
IMHO, the naming convention of OpenCV is quite confusing here.

Answer (score 1):

CV_32F means a 32 bit floating point number.  CV_32S means a 32 bit signed integer.  I'm sure you can guess what CV_64F stands for.  The internet is full of references for the ranges that different data types can take on, [here](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080503144541AAqrW0D) is 32S for instance.

Comment: That far I have already got. But does OpenCV use the whole range? Meaning numeric_limits<float>::max() will be white and numeric_limits<float>::min() will be black for a CV_32FC1?

Comment: for CV_32F, 0.0 is black and 1.0 is white.