# OpenCV C++: Conversion from CV_32F to CV8U using converTo is giving unexpected values

Tags: c++, opencv

```
cv::Mat x(2,2,CV_32F);
x.at<float>(0,0)=0.7;
x.at<float>(0,1) = 0.8;
x.at<float>(1,0) = 0.72;
x.at<float>(1,1) = 0.68;
x.convertTo( x, CV_8U, 255, 0  );
std::cout << x.at<int>(0,0)  << std::endl;
std::cout << x.at<int>(0,1)  << std::endl;
std::cout << x.at<float>(1,0)  << std::endl; // I deliberately put <float> just to see what happens
std::cout << x.at<int>(1,1)  << std::endl;
```

The output is:

-1380397902
1
1.54154e-40
0

I was expecting an output like:

178
204
184
173

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Since when is C++ 1-indexed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your Mat is CV_8U now, you will have to access it as

```
x.at<uchar>(1,1)
```

the next problem will be printing out the number correctly, cout, seeing a char , will try to print a letter, so you will have to cast it to int:

```
std::cout << int(x.at<uchar>(0,0))  << std::endl;
```

then, if your mat is 2x2, you *can't* access an element at 2,2, this is out of bounds, and will lead to UB. !

(in c++, we index from 0..n-1, right ?)

so, here, the corrected example:

```
cv::Mat x(2,2,CV_32F);
x.at<float>(0,0)=0.7;
x.at<float>(1,0) = 0.8;
x.at<float>(0,1) = 0.72;
x.at<float>(1,1) = 0.68;
Mat y;

x.convertTo( y, CV_8U, 255, 0  );
cout << int(y.at<uchar>(0,0))  << std::endl;
cout << int(y.at<uchar>(1,0))  << std::endl;
cout << int(y.at<uchar>(0,1))  << std::endl;
cout << int(y.at<uchar>(1,1))  << std::endl;

cerr << x << endl;
cerr << y << endl;
```

---

```
178
204
184
173
[0.69999999, 0.72000003;
  0.80000001, 0.68000001]
[178, 184;
  204, 173]
```

---

Comment: Thanks berak for the very helpful answer! I was assuming things which I should not. Here is a post that shows which other data types are associated with which other OpenCV types.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484475/what-are-the-upper-and-lower-limits-and-types-of-pixel-values-in-opencv